# Getting [jwt is not defined] while fetching data from MongoDB backend -

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, jwt, mern

the question is pretty self explanatory. I am registering/signing up users in a mongoDB database. They are being registered fine and an accesstoken [jwt based] is also being generated.
Now, when I go to query the database to fetch the list of users I am getting that error -
***jwt is not defined.***

It is worthwhile to mention that users also in my backend can have two type of roles - basic and admin. And only an admin user can fetch list of all users by sending accessToken in the header as Bearer authorization parameter.

I have 2 main files in my backend project structure that uses ***jwt.access methods like jwt.verify or jwt.signIn***; these are the server.js and userController.js [a separate file where I have written all individual db related methods].

As far as I am concerned, all necessary packages are there in my project - express, node, jwa, jws, jsonwebtoken, mongo, mongoose, bcrypt, cors etc. So what is the trouble?

My route.js -->

```
const User = require('../models/user.model');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

const { roles } = require('../models/roles');


const JWT_SECRET = "$#GR24T4344$#$@#%ETWWTEME%$6";

async function hashPassword(password) {
    return await bcrypt.hash(password, 10);
}


async function validatePassword(plainPassword, hashedPassword) {
    return await bcrypt.compare(plainPassword, hashedPassword);
}


exports.grantAccess = function (action, resource) {
    return async (req, res, next) => {
        try {
            const permission = roles.can(req.user.role)[action](resource);
            if (!permission.granted) {
                return res.status(401).json({
                    error: "You don't have enough permission to perform this action"
                });
            }
            next();
        } catch (error) {
            next(error);
        }
    }
}


exports.allowIfLoggedin = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const user = res.locals.loggedInUser;
        if (!user)
            return res.status(401).json({
                error: "You need to be logged in to access this route"
            });
        req.user = user;
        next();
    } catch (error) {
        next(error);
    }
}


exports.signup = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const { role, email, password } = req.body;
        const hashedPassword = await hashPassword(password);
        const newUser = new User({ email, password: hashedPassword, role: role || "basic" });
        const accessToken = jwt.sign({ userId: newUser._id }, JWT_SECRET, {
            expiresIn: "1d"
        });
        newUser.accessToken = accessToken;
        await newUser.save();
        res.json({
            data: newUser,
            message: "You have signed up successfully"
        });
    } catch (error) {
        next(error);
    }
}


exports.login = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const { email, password } = req.body;
        const user = await User.findOne({ email });
        if (!user)
            return next(new Error('Email does not exist'));
        const validPassword = await validatePassword(password, user.password);
        if (!validPassword)
            return next(new Error('Password is not correct'));
        const accessToken = jwt.sign({ userId: user._id }, JWT_SECRET, {
            expiresIn: "1d"
        });
        await User.findByIdAndUpdate(user._id, { accessToken });
        res.status(200).json({
            data: { email: user.email, role: user.role },
            accessToken
        });
    } catch (error) {
        next(error);
    }
}


exports.getUsers = async (req, res, next) => {
    const users = await User.find({});
    res.status(200).json({
        data: users
    });
}


exports.getUser = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const userId = req.params.userId;
        const user = await User.findById(userId);
        if (!user)
            return next(new Error('User does not exist'));
        res.status(200).json({
            data: user
        });
    } catch (error) {
        next(error);
    }
}


exports.updateUser = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const { role } = req.body;
        const userId = req.params.userId;
        await User.findByIdAndUpdate(userId, { role });
        const user = await User.findById(userId);
        res.status(200).json({
            data: user
        });
    } catch (error) {
        next(error);
    }
}


exports.deleteUser = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const userId = req.params.userId;
        await User.findByIdAndDelete(userId);
        res.status(200).json({
            data: null,
            message: 'User has been deleted'
        });
    } catch (error) {
        next(error);
    }
}
```

My server.js -->

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const PORT = 4000;
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const playerRoutes = express.Router();
const userRoutes = express.Router();
const userController = require('./controllers/userController');
const user_routes = require('./apiroutes/route');
const app = express();

const JWT_SECRET = "$#GR24T4344$#$@#%ETWWTEME%$6";


const users = "users";

require("dotenv").config({path: __dirname+ '../.env'});



let Player = require('./models/player.model');
let User = require('./models/user.model');

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(
    bodyParser.urlencoded({
        extended: false
    })
);

mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/playerDB', function (err, db) {
    if (err)
        throw err;
    db.createCollection(users, function (err, resp) {
        if (err)
            throw err;
        console.log("Collection created!");

    });
}, { useNewUrlParser: true });


const connection = mongoose.connection;

connection.once('open', function () {
    console.log("MongoDB database connection established successfully");
});

..... blablablaaaa


app.use('/playerDB', playerRoutes);


app.use(async (req, res, next) => {

    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

    if (req.headers["x-access-token"]) {
        try {
            const accessToken = req.headers["x-access-token"];
            const { userId, exp } = await jwt.verify(accessToken, JWT_SECRET);
            // If token has expired
            if (exp < Date.now().valueOf() / 1000) {
                return res.status(401).json({
                    error: "JWT token has expired, please login to obtain a new one"
                });
            }
            res.locals.loggedInUser = await User.findById(userId);
            next();
        } catch (error) {
            next(error);
        }
    } else {
        next();
    }


});


app.use('/users', user_routes);


app.listen(PORT, function () {
    console.log("Server is running on Port: " + PORT);
});
```

I hope you understand my approach and scenario? Can you guess, where it could have gone wrong? Any idea?
Missing npm packages or something more critical?

Look forward to some hints on this problem! Can't seem to figure out a way!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seems you forgot to add this line to server.js

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
```

While register and login, this didn't caused a problem, because for these requests,  req.headers["x-access-token"] was null, and  the code didn't reach the if block where you used jwt, but one a request with this header came (like getUsers) the code tried to use jwt.verify, but since jwt wasn't imported it gave error.

Comment: hi @suleymanshah - let me try out this edit as per your suggest. yep, I guess it makes sense, because during signup, no header or token are sent. it's just some data sent in plain x-www.-form-urlencoded format...    meanwhile, here is the link to my entire backend source code ---> https://1drv.ms/u/s!AqxwD_-HSbSQgR3hvA9p0U_voGvS?e=hBY4bg     . Could you take a look, and suggest some possible edits or improvements to make this more streamlined. Actually I intend to use/call this backend from a front end ReactJS app. Isuues of CORS and all that.......

Comment: Hello @PrabirChoudhury  mixing other questions to the original question is not recommended in stackoverflow,  if my answer works, you can consider accepting it as an answer. If you ask another question in a different post I will try to answer if I can do.

Comment: @PrabirChoudhury  did this answer resolve your problem?  For code reviews you can use https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: hi @suleymanshah kindly give me a little bit of time. For sure I will upvote and 'mark as answer' your comment. I got caught up in some other works, I will be trying out your solution tomorrow; I will revert back with feedback,

Comment: hi @suleymanshah no I am getting a different error now - 404 Not Found

Cannot GET /users. I added the require statement to my server.js also.   Kindly refer to the downloadable package of my whole source code if you need. Look forward to your feedback. Thanks,

Comment: @PrabirChoudhury you had better to ask a new question about your new issue. I can't solve all your applications problems in one question, I hope you understand, this is not the way stackoverflow works.

Comment: @PrabirChoudhury this is the last comment about this issue, you need to use this url to get users   http://localhost:4000/users/users

Comment: Hi @suleymanshah - pl note this is the original problem itself. The problem where I was unable to fetch users and the jwt related error was appearing. Two different error messages appeared and this post contains updates of that. I appreciate your response and accordingwise will try out this route. Thanks.